# Import error Anki

Tags: python-2.7, anki

There is an error when I imported deck to Anki. The error is in the image (I'm sorry I could not paste the error here). It has something to do with

> IOError: zipimport: can not open file ~/Downloads/Anki.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2-7/site-packages.zip

[image]

How can I fix this error.